# how to print if a line contains specific pattern and not to print if it not contain the pattern

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

```
">16RI1_0 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15012:1778 1:N:0:0 
TATCCGGATTTACTGGGTGTAAAGGGAGCGTAGGCGGCCATGCAAGTCAGAAGTGAAAAC
">16RA2_1 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15923:1780 1:N:0:0 
TTGTCCGGATTTATTGGGCGTAAAGCGAGCGCAGGCGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGC
">0VC3_7 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15805:1805 1:N:0:0 TCATGAAGAACTCCGATCGCGAAGGCAAGTGTCCGGGGTGCAACTGACGCTGAGGCTCGAA
">11VI2_15 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:17657:1817 1:N:0:0 
GCGGCTTACTGGACTGTAACTGACGTTGAGGCTCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGGCTC
```

Hello, I have a file containing information like this. I want to print all the lines starting with ">" sign and the next line but there is a condition the line starting with ">" sign should contain the letter V. Please help me.

Comment: The fasta file in the question has improperly formatted header lines, and one sequence lien is not on its own line. Please reformat.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and clarify. Is this your actual file or do you have a real fasta format file? Can we assume that all sequence information will always be on a single line? Fasta allows multiple sequence lines per entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `sed` (standard on Linux system), you can get the header line (containing a `V` anywhere on it)  and the first line of the sequence from a fasta file like this:

```
sed -n '/^>.*V/,+1p' sequence.fa
```

This is assuming that the fasta file is properly formatted.

The `-n` turns off the default output and `/^>.*V/,+1p` will print any header line with a `V` in it, together with the immediately following line.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to print all the lines starting with ">" sign and the next line
>   but there is a condition the line starting with ">" sign should
>   contain the letter V.

This `grep` seems to work:

```
grep -A 1 '^">.*V'
```

Example:

```
grep -A 1 '^">.*V' file 
">0VC3_7 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15805:1805 1:N:0:0 TCATGAAGAACTCCGATCGCGAAGGCAAGTGTCCGGGGTGCAACTGACGCTGAGGCTCGAA
">11VI2_15 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:17657:1817 1:N:0:0 
GCGGCTTACTGGACTGTAACTGACGTTGAGGCTCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGGCTC
```

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I want to print all the lines starting with ">" sign and the next line but there is a condition the line starting with ">" sign should contain the letter V

That's a good job for awk:

```
$ awk '/^">.*V/{print $0;getline line; print line}' input.txt                                                            
">0VC3_7 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:15805:1805 1:N:0:0 
TCATGAAGAACTCCGATCGCGAAGGCAAGTGTCCGGGGTGCAACTGACGCTGAGGCTCGAA
">11VI2_15 M01230:42:000000000-AWMRD:1:1101:17657:1817 1:N:0:0 
GCGGCTTACTGGACTGTAACTGACGTTGAGGCTCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGGCTC
```

Comment: Thaks a lot. it worked